# SP2013 Toolbar keeps loading invalid http json response headers for commandui.ashx

Tags: json, forefront, networking, toolbar, http-headers

Dear smart people out there,

we published SP2013 via UAG 2010 sp4.

The toolbar keeps showing 'Loading ...'
In javascript there is a Deserialization error.

## My http response for the commandui.ashx

### headers

```
Cache-Control:private
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 22 Jan 2015 23:01:06 GMT
Expires:Fri, 22 Jan 2016 23:01:06 GMT
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices:15.0.0.4561
request-id:d860e29c-933b-9069-110a-896f36285dd1
Server:MyWebServer
Server:MyWebServer
Set-cookie:NLSessionSpreauthnappsPersistForOffice=b/aZI5ePhNl6DGrp4hxpUruMARMFDkeeM+jCVbbC5t8CFmeDveN7P0I+ft8OLI02l+rIdu1GcqM7jVj83pDppTC9jtGmKDTc0V9kZg76mxxNddH1fHpxnvAmZwudUxnO;path=/;secure;domain=.company.com;expires=Thu 22-Jan-2015 23:01:21 GMT
Set-cookie:NLSessionSpreauthnapps=b/aZI5ePhNl6EkVp4hxpUruMARMFDkeeM+jCVbbC5t8CFmeDveN7P0I+ft8OLI02l+rIdu15rTM7jVj83pDppTC7jtGmKDTc0V9kZg76mxxNddH1fHpxnvAmZwudUxnO;path=/;secure;domain=.company.com
SPRequestGuid:d860e29c-933b-9069-110a-896f36285dd1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-AspNet-Version:
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-FRAME-OPTIONS:SAMEORIGIN
X-MS-InvokeApp:1; RequireReadOnly
X-Powered-By:
X-Powered-By:
X-SharePointHealthScore:0
```

### body

```
bbe8
{"name" : "CommandUI","attrs":                
{"xmlns":"http:\u002f\u002fschemas.microsoft.com\u002fsharepoint\u002f"},children:
[{"name" : "Templates","attrs": {},children:[{"name" : "RibbonTemplates","attrs": 
{"Id":"Ribbon.Templates"},children:[{"name" : "GroupTemplate","attrs": 
{"Id":"Ribbon.Templates.ManageViewsGroup"},children:[{"name" : "Layout","attrs": 

... more content ...

{"Id":"Ribbon.Tabs.InfoPathListDisplayTab","Command":"InfoPathListDisplayTab","Description":"","Title":"View"}}]}]}]}
0
```

Did you ever encounter a similar problem? 
It seems this problem started when upgrading UAG to SP1.

All advice is welcome!

Thanks in advance,
AllWorkNoPlay

Answer (score 0):

You mention UAG SP1, but for SharePoint 2013 support, you need SP3, so that would be the 1st thing to check and confirm. Beyond the installation itself, you also need to RECREATE the application (the publishing item) afterwards, as that re-configures some of the publishing rules that have changed with the SP.

If, with all the above, you still have the error, let us know.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the cause, there was manipulation in file

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Forefront Unified Access Gateway\von\Conf\WebSites\preauthnapps\conf\CustomUpdate\WhlFiltAppWrap_HTTPS.xml

A gzip header was added for SharePoint15 app.

Removing the entry for SharePoint15 solved the problem.